# Copy Text from UITextView inside a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I have a tableview cell that has an image view, a UILabel and a TextView. I want the user to be able to select text from the TextView when they longPress on the TextView.

I have created a Gesture recogniser for the cell, and when the user long presses on the cell, the gesture recogniser gets called, but I don't get a menu or a cursor for the user to be able to select text and then copy it. Below is the code to attach long press to the UITableView cell

```
  UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longPressRecognizer =     [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self   action:@selector(LongPressgesture:)];
 [tableView addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
```

I also have the following code that gets called

```
- (void)LongPressgesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"Long press Ended .................");
     }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Long press detected .....................");
    }
}
```

The function gets called, so I see the message "Long press Detected" on the output log, but I don't get the menu to copy text. I tried creating a menu on the Long Press section as this:

```
    UIMenuItem *menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Copy" action:@selector(copyText:)];

    UIMenuController *menuCont = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];

    [menuCont setTargetRect:CGRectMake(10, 100, 400, 400) inView:tableview];

    menuCont.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowDown;
    menuCont.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:menuItem];
    [menuCont setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

But the copy text function is not called, and there is no menu.

Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that your "Long press detected" message will be called for many different state changes include "Began", "Changed", "Cancelled", "Failed", and "Possible".

Comment: UIMenuItem is a component of a larger cluster.  The thing you should look at first is UIMenuController.  Consider also that UIAlertController might be simple enough (or even just copy the text unconditionally??).  Finally, attach the gesture recognizer to the cell, not the table, so you'll have an easier time figuring out which text needs copying.

Comment: @maddy, thank you. I have tried with the other states too, but it still doesn't work, I don't get the copy menu ...

Comment: @dah thank you. I have attached the gesture recogniser to the cell, but it has no effect. I have made the TextView editable and Selectable in the Story Board.

Comment: @user3079872, I understand.  Attaching the GR to the cell will help later (when you want to know which cell's text to copy).  The immediate problem I indicated is that UIMenuItem by itself doesn't do anything.